# Sql Query: Return Results that exclude one value, include another in same column

Tags: sql-server, join, subquery, union

I'm attempting to pull from a few tables in containing

1. unique `PropertyID` record and
2. `ContactRoleID` and
3. `LocationID`

`PropertyID`s are unique identifiers, but can have multiple `ContactRoleID`s.

- `ContactRoleID = 3` = Recorded Owner (an LLC, Shell Company, etc)
- `ContactRoleID = 7` = True Owner (actual company behind LLC)

I'm trying to find a way to figure out where we are missing true owners on `PropertyID`s that we should be able to add, because they are already associated with a recorded owner on another `PropertyID`.

Therefore, the query would be something to the affect of (#3-5 represent result list):

1. Find all `LocationID`s on `PropertyID`s that have both `ContactRoleID = 3 AND ContactRoleID = 7`, then
2. Find all `PropertyID`s that have `ContactRoleID = 3` from first query, but no `ContactRoleID = 7`
3. Return the `LocationID`s of `ContactRoleID = 3` on `PropertyID`s missing `ContactRoleID = 7`
4. Return the `PropertyID`s in #3
5. Return the `LocationID` of the `ContactRoleID = 7` that matches `ContactRoleID = 3` from process #1 (suspected true owner)
6. Return the referencing `PropertyID` that had both `ContactRoleID`s from process #1 (referencing `PropertyID`)

I tried by best but couldn't figure it out. I've done query #1, but #2 won't work (it still pulls in PropertyIDs that have ContactRoleID =7. I think I'm missing a union, or maybe a correlated subquery. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Here's my attempt at #2 (haven't even tried to go past that).

```
USE Enterprise

--RETURNS THE LOCATIONIDs OF THE RECORDED OWNERS FOR ALL PROPERTYIDs WITHOUT TRUE OWNERS--
SELECT
   DISTINCT P1.PropertyID
   ,PC1.LocationID as R_Owner
FROM
   enterprise.dbo.Property AS P1
left join
   enterprise.dbo.PropertyContact As PC1 on PC1.PropertyID = P1.PropertyID
WHERE       
   PC1.ContactRoleID in ('3') 
   AND P1.PropertyID in 
       --RETURNS ALL PROPERTYIDs OF PROPERTIES WITHOUT TRUE OWNERS--
       (SELECT P2.PropertyID 
        FROM enterprise.dbo.Property AS P2
        left join enterprise.dbo.PropertyContact As PC2 on PC2.PropertyID = P2.PropertyID
        where PC2.ContactRoleID <> 7 
          AND PC2.EndDate IS NULL
          and P1.PropertyID = PC2.PropertyID
          AND PC1.PropertyContactID = PC2.PropertyContactID)
```

Comment: what is the table structure for both tables property and property contact?  I don't see how location is involved other than primary contact location Id.

Comment: @Qbert. Thanks for replying. There are two tables. 'Property' and 'PropertyContact'. 'PropertyContact' has a foreign key 'PropertyID' associated with the 'Property' table. 'PropertyContact' is where I get the 'PropertyContactID' and the 'LocationID'.  Did that answer your question?

Comment: Sample data and a http://sqlfiddle.com/ would help as well.  I keep looking at this and thinking all you're really after is  "figure out where we are missing true owners on PropertyIDs that we should be able to add, because they are already associated with a recorded owner on another PropertyID." in which case I think some of what you're doing is overhead.  A self join of sorts should be able to identify what your after but I can't visualize it without some sample data and table structures. Not just what you have in query)